# How to reference cells in a conditional formatting formula rule?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I wold like to use the value of the current cell into to "Custom formula is.."
when using conditional formatting.

I would like to enter a "Custom formula", which will check if value of cell is ether'a' or 'b'.

What will be correct syntax?

Comment: Just refer to the top-left cell of the range to which the conditional format applies (e.g. `A1`).

Comment: What do you mean by "current cell" - the cell the conditional format is in, or the currently selected cell?

Comment: F.ex : I want to check if the value of a cell is ether 'a' or 'b', and if true, then color the the same cell with blue.
I would like to do it in one "custom formula"/same condiotional formatting rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

Select the range the conditional formatting is to apply to, say C5:C10. Format, Conditional formatting…, Add new rule, Format cells if…, **Custom formula is**:

```
=or(c5="a",c5="b")
```

Select your Formatting style (Default may suit) and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts , that help me one step ahead :-)
Can you also point out for me syntax if i want to test if cell contains a tekst/letter? Find? Contains? or other?